# Show that $\dim U + \dim U^\bot \geq \dim V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, bilinear-form

$V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $F$. Given a symmetric bilinear form $b$ with $U$ a subspace of $V$ show
$$\dim U + \dim U^\bot \geq \dim V.$$

Here I cannot assume that $b$ is non-degenerate. I can show that equality holds if $b$ is non-degenerate, but how would I approach showing this inequality?

Comment: The worst that can happen is that $U \cap U^\perp$ has positive dimension  for a non-degenerate form...

Comment: I see. So then I can apply the fact that $\dim(U) + \dim(U^\bot) = \dim (U + U^\bot) + \dim (U \cap U^\bot)$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks! I think I was able to work out the proof. I was struggling since I couldn't figure out how to extend the proof for equality which I had seen before to not use the fact that $b$ was non-degenerate.

Comment: You could write that proof as an answer and accept it, that way the solution (if correct) will persist (for others to find later) and you'd gain rep points.